# Using variable in Powershell task, inline script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to write a very easy **inline** script which should update the variable *NameSuffix* to a new value. I wanted to use a local helper variable *newVar*.

```
Write-Host "Detected version: $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)";
$newVar = "v$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Build).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Release)";
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=NameSuffix;]$(newVar)");
```

But Visual Studio Online / VSTS tells me when the scrips runs:

> The term 'newVar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Using a variable this way seems common in script files and works on the command line.

So how can I accomplish this simple assignment of a variable (with a concated value) as a build task in VSO/VSTS?

Comment: Should that not be `$($newVar)` ?

Comment: Yes, it works with `$($newVar)` and also with `$newVar` in the 3rd line as demonstrated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, the issue is because `newvar` should be `$newvar` to correctly reference the variable. The `$()` part is the subexpression operator, which is usually used within a String when you have a non-simple single variable that you want expanded to a string (such as accessing the property of a variable).

In this case, your variable is simple, so you can do away with the sub-expression operator I believe. Equally I'm not sure the outer-brackets or semi-colons are needed, simplifying your code to this:

```
Write-Host "Detected version: $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)"
$newVar = "v$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Major).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Minor).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Build).$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion.Release)"
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NameSuffix;]$newVar"
```

Comment: This works. The whole time I was thinking the second line would be causing the problem. In addition `$($newVar)` works too. With the parts of `$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion)` it means that `AssemblyInfo.AssemblyVersion` is not a simple variable? Got that defined by the _Assembly Info Reader_ plugin from the market place.

Comment: Yeah although again on reflection I'd think you'd need a dollar at the start inside the brackets too. Does it currently work correctly?

Comment: Yes it does, like you posted. Did not yet try an dollar inside the brackets though.